# How to Zoom UIWebView in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, url, uiwebview, zooming

I am new to this technology,

I am loading webpage in my `webview`,

I didn't set `scalePageToFit` property. without using this property i want to do Zooming In and Out on my webview.

**is it Possible ?**

Here is my Code snippet,

```
NSURL *url2=[NSURL URLWithString:str1];
NSURLRequest *req2=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url2];
[webView1 loadRequest:req2];
[webView1.scrollView setZoomScale:2.0 animated:TRUE];
[webView1 release];
```

str1 is my `url` i tried this but, still i am unable to zoom my web view in simulator.

**Any help will be appreciated.**

***Thanks In Advance !***

Comment: see this : http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Mobile-Applications/14635-uiwebview-zoom.html

Comment: I mentioned in my question i do not want to use `scalePageToFit` property

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `scalePageToFit` property to YES.

Comment: I am loading a webpage which contains Graph, i want to zoom that graph not webpage, when i write `scalePageToFit ` it zooms webpage, not graph.

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView is having scrollView as a property. Use ScrollView's delegate method

```
– scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:
```

This might help you.

Follow [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010281) : This might give you some clue. how to zoom the scrollview.